# How to create Operating Hours for Apex Testing

Tags: apex, unit-test, field-service-lightning

I can't really find a solution for this, but does anyone can help me with creating Operating Hours for Apex Testing? I'm not quite sure what I have to create? Only the Operating Hours - record or more?

Comment: what do you mean by "Operating Hours"? Do you mean Business Hours?

Comment: @Patlatus Operating Hours are for Field Service Lightning 
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fs_oh_fields.htm&type=5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparantly it's just enough to create a record for Operating Hours.

```
OperatingHours oh = new OperatingHours();
oh.Name = 'TestOH';
insert oh;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a record for [TimeSlot](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_timeslot.htm) in your apex test class. Once that is inserted you will be able to test it.

Comment: So I have to create an 'Operating Hours'-record and a TimeSlot-record to be able to use an Operating Hours Id? We have a custom object that has a required lookup to Operating Hours.